# Complex Ellipse to Cartesian Form

Tags: complex-numbers, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I have a problem, where the equation of my ellipse is:

$$1=\frac{x^2}{75}+\frac{y^2}{56.25}$$

and I have been able to translate the equation to a complex form of 

$$|z+2.5\sqrt{3}|+|z-2.5\sqrt{3}|=10\sqrt{3}.$$

 Now the problem is being able to solve and show the method of substituting and rearranging from the complex form to the cartesian form. I know the $z$ has to be substituted with $x+yi$ but the rest is unknown. Please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the ellipse

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

there are several ways to express it in the complex plane. Some are shown in the other answers. Here are two direct expressions for $z(\theta),~\theta\in[0,2\pi]$.

$$
z=a\cos\theta+ib\sin\theta
$$
$$
r=\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta}}
$$
$$
z=re^{i\theta}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ be an equation of the ellipse.

We need $$|z-c|+|z+c|=2a$$

Thus, $$c^2=a^2-b^2$$ or
$$c^2=18.75,$$
which gives $c=2.5\sqrt3$, $a=5\sqrt3$ and since  in the Gauss plain $z=x+yi$ it's just the point $(x,y)$,

we get the answer:
$$|z-2.5\sqrt3|+|z+2.5\sqrt3|=10\sqrt3.$$
Done!

P.S. $|z-2.5\sqrt3|$ it's the distance between $M(x,y)$ and $F_1(2.5\sqrt3,0)$;

$|z+2.5\sqrt3|$ it's the distance between $M(x,y)$ and $F_2(-2.5\sqrt3,0)$.

By the ellipse definition
$$MF_1+MF_2=constant,$$
where $F_1$ and $F_2$ are different points and our $constant>0.$

In our case the $constant=2a=10\sqrt3.$

Also, we have
$$|z-2.5\sqrt3|=|x-2.5\sqrt{3}+yi|=\sqrt{(x-2.5\sqrt3)^2+y^2}=MF_1,$$
where $M(x,y)$ and $F_1(2.5\sqrt3,0)$.

Comment: Yes I understand how that is completed but I am having trouble working from the complex to the cartesian form @michaelrozenberg

Comment: @Carlos Bray  In the Gauss plain $z=x+yi$ it's just the point $(x,y)$. It's all.

Comment: Yes but how do you use that and translate it bake to the original form, because I have substituted that in for z but don't know how to rearrange to solve @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: @Carlos Bray I added something.